# What does this.timeout() do in a mocha test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am new to javascript, I would like to know what does `this.timeout()` do in this mocha test.

```js
it('TestConnect', async function() {
    this.timeout(40000);
});
```

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#timeouts

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Thanks for sharing, I already looked into it, it says how to set timeouts, but didn't explain what is a timeout. Does the program exit after specified number of seconds or does the program wait for specified number of seconds before executing ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
describe('a suite of tests', function() {
  this.timeout(500);

  it('should take less than 500ms', function(done) {
    setTimeout(done, 600); // fails
  });

  it('should take less than 500ms as well', function(done) {
    setTimeout(done, 250); // passes
  });
});
```

> I already looked into it, it says how to set timeouts, but didn't explain what is a timeout. Does the program exit after specified number of seconds or does the program wait for specified number of seconds before executing ?

The program doesn't necessarily exit, but the above (example) suite fails. The `timeout` parameter just means that tests in that suite, or a specific test that it has to call `done` within the timeout period else the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

In mocha, timeout is the maximum time test will wait for `done` before set test as failed.

So, for example, your `timeout` is 5000 (5 seconds) and the code has a loop that spent 7 seconds to iterate over all object. Then the test will fail even data is ok because timeout is triggered before `done()` is called.

Is true not exists a great explanation, but in [this docs](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha) is defined as:

> Sets timeout threshold value.

Threshold is the time when you decide test should fail.